# java array with void/methods

Tags: java, arrays, json, void

My code look awful, and i want do it better way.

```
if (e == null && !result.isJsonNull() && result.get("code").getAsInt() == 200) {
JsonArray array = result.get("data").getAsJsonObject().get("products").getAsJsonArray();
ProductDAO productDAO = new ProductDAO(getApplicationContext());

for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    Product product = new Product();
    if (!isProduct(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsString())) {
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_amount").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_amount").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setVatAmount(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_amount").getAsDouble());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_rate").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_rate").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setVatRate(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_rate").getAsDouble());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_rate_s").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_rate_s").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setVatRateS(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("_vat_rate_s").getAsString());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("brutto_value").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("brutto_value").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setBruttoValue(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("brutto_value").getAsDouble());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("count").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("count").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setCount(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("count").getAsDouble());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("id").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("id").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setFinettoID(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("lp").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("lp").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setLp(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("lp").getAsInt());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("name").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("name").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setName(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("netto_value").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("netto_value").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setNettoValue(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("netto_value").getAsDouble());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("price").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("price").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setPrice(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("price").getAsDouble());
        }
        if (!array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("unit").isJsonNull() && !array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("unit").toString().equals("")) {
            product.setUnit(array.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("unit").getAsString());
        }
        productDAO.save(product);
    }
}
```

Is some way to create array with void/methods (setters)? I can cut some this json. This will be some better. But i want do it more better.

Comment: Since you aren't having a problem, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit.

Comment: Oh my bad. Next time i will post in good place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create some methods like this (one for each type):

```
private String getAsString(String key, JsonObject jsonObject) {
    if (jsonObject.get(key).isJsonNull() && !jsonObject.get(key).toString().equals("")) {
        return jsonObject.get(key).getAsString());
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you can just do this:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = array.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

product.setVatAmount(getAsDouble("_vat_amount", jsonObject));
product.setVatRate(getAsDouble("_vat_rate", jsonObject));
product.setVatRateS(getAsString("_vat_rate_s", jsonObject));
```

and so on.